# Django using add to add a ManyToManyField where the object is 'self'

Tags: python, django

When I execute the following code profile is added to user_profile.following as was expected, but user_profile is also added to profile.following (this is unwanted) why is this happening, I have a feeling it has something to do with the ForeignKey being 'self', but I'm not sure how to fix it...Here is the view:

```
def follow(request, profile_id):
    user = request.user
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=profile_id)
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=user.id)

    user_profile.following.add(profile)


    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('twitter:profile', args=(profile.id,)))
```

and the model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bio = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

Comment: Well I finally found the answer to this after some more snooping, in case anyone else wants to know the solution:  in the model, following should be models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)

Comment: You should post this as an answer and than accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally found the answer to this after some more snooping, in case anyone else wants to know the solution: in the model, following should be

```
following = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
```